# Jhipster build production command with Maven return Error

Tags: jhipster

i try to build to production my jhipster project ( Spring with Angular 7 ) but i receive a lot Errors i add this trace from my log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node.exe',
1 verbose cli 'C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli 'run',
1 verbose cli 'webpack:prod:main' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewebpack:prod:main',
4 verbose run-script 'webpack:prod:main',
4 verbose run-script 'postwebpack:prod:main' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.0.0prewebpack:prod:main: frontend@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: frontend@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: PATH: C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Eventim\frontend\node_modules.bin;C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Eventim\frontend\node_modules.bin;C:\Eventim\frontend\node;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: CWD: C:\Eventim\frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle 'npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: Returned: code: 2 signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.0.0webpack:prod:main: Failed to exec webpack:prod:main script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Eventim\frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node.exe" "C:\Eventim\frontend\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack:prod:main"
18 verbose node v10.13.0
19 verbose npm v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error frontend@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Reproduce the error
i try to go to production with maven build war file with this command :
./mvnw -Pprod package

JHipster Version(s)
5.7.0

JHipster configuration
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing jhipster:info
INFO! Options: from-cli: true
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

JHipster Version(s)
C:\
`-- (empty)

cat: no such file or directory: .yo-rc.json

java version "1.8.0_192"

node: v11.2.0

npm: 6.4.1

yeoman: 2.0.5

yarn: 1.12.3

working on windows 10

Comment: You did not run `jhipster info` in your project's directory (see error `no such file or directory: .yo-rc.json`) which means it's useless . Anyway, is this the first time you run a prod build?

Comment: Yes, this is the first time i running the prod build

Comment: Does it fail the same when you run it directly with npm without using mvnw? `npm run webpack:prod:main` Sometimes, it could fail if you don't have enough RAM or using a 32 bit version of node, try `node -p "process.arch"` Some tips here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8065

Comment: when running the npn run webpack:prod:main it fails with other error - 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error frontend@0.0.0 lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.0.0 lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]

Comment: Please edit your question with additional log, if tslint failed you should have other log statement to guide you to the root cause.